# Tower of Hanoi Variation - is it possible to determine how many times a pole should be used?

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to make a variation on the tower of Hanoi game. I've four discs and three poles.

According to the formula (2 ^ DiscAmount) - 1, this game can be solved in fifteen moves, minimum.

The variation I'm trying to do, if at all possible, is to limit the number of times a pole can be used, forcing the player to think ahead and not unnecessarily move a disc to any pole. If, for example, he makes a mistake, and moves a disc to pole B when it should've been to pole C, that's one use for pole B that was essentially wasted, and may come back to bite him later when he actually needs pole B.

So, is there a way to find out the minimum times a pole will be used?

Comment: How is the number of times a pole has been used any different than counting the number of moves?

Comment: There is basically only one way to solve the towers of Hanoi. At each point in the game apart from at the start you have three moves available, and only one of them leads to the shortest solution (at the start you have two moves available, and they both lead to a shortest solution). You can ask how many times each pole is used during such a solution, but there is basically no choice involved in solving the game if you want to do it in $2^d - 1$ moves.

Comment: @Carser, hmmm, I wasn't 100% if it was a good idea. It's part of a game I'm making. Same concept, except the discs are ants, and the poles are sugar canes. Move an ant to any cane, and it will start eating it. At the lowest level, it doesn't matter how many times a player moves, for as long as he still has sugar canes left. Probably should've thought this out more.

Comment: @zack_falcon It sounds like a fun game!

Comment: @Carser, thanks, but I need to think on it a bit more. Feel free to vote the question to be closed if it's not solvable.